# Get single object from primary key of realm object

Tags: ios, realm

I have realm object which is in objective-c class (our project is mix&match between swift and objective-c)

I know that I can access

`[ClassName objectForPrimaryKey:]` in objc

but I don't know how can I use this method in swift file?

is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case if you are using Realm as an Objective-C library in Swift, then:

```
let object = ClassName(forPrimaryKey: primaryKey)
```

Answer (score 2):

In case of Swift you should use the following code:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let object = realm.object(ofType: ClassName.self, forPrimaryKey: primaryKey)
```